# How to improve this functional python trial division routine?

Tags: python, functional-programming, integer

The following functional program factors an integer by trial division. I am not interested in improving the efficiency (but not in decreasing it either), I am interested how it can be made better or neater using functional constructions. I just seem to think there are a few tweaks to make this pattern more consistent and tight (this is hard to describe), without turning it into boilerplate.

```
def primes(limit): 
        return (x for x in xrange(2,limit+1) if len(factorization(x)) == 1) 

def factor(factors,p): 
        n = factors.pop() 
        while n % p == 0: 
                n /= p 
                factors += [p] 
        return factors+[n] if n > 1 else factors 

def factorization(n): 
        from math import sqrt 
        return reduce(factor,primes(int(sqrt(n))),[n])
```

For example, `factorization(1100)` yields:

```
[2,2,5,5,11]
```

It would be great if it could all fit on one line or into two functions that looked a lot tighter -- I'm sure there must be some way, but I can not see it yet. What can be done?

Comment: so `factorization` is the function you want out of this? because you don't need `primes` to get it (note also that factorization calls primes and primes calls factorization, that does not look good).

Comment: Why would that not be good? I thought it looked cool. Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functional recursive implementation:

```
def factorization(num, start=2):
    candidates = xrange(start, int(sqrt(num)) + 1)
    factor = next((x for x in candidates if num % x == 0), None)
    return ([factor] + factorization(num / factor, factor) if factor else [num])    

print factorization(1100)
#=> [2, 2, 5, 5, 11]
```

Check [this](https://github.com/tokland/pyeuler/blob/master/pyeuler/toolset.py).

Comment: Cool thanks. But I dislike recursion because of stack overflows or max recursion depth. I will try to understand your code though!

Comment: I like get_cardinal_name !

Comment: Note that the function only calls itself for factors of a number, not for every n being tested, so you'll need a number with thousands of factor to reach the limit. Anyway, since you are learning on Python and functional programming, a hint: 1) lists (arrays) don't play nice with functional programming. 2) not having tail-recursion hinders functional approaches.

Comment: Okay, cool tips about those things. Thanks. I will try to understand this better!